# Access ssh keys during docker-compose build in flask project

Tags: python, docker, flask, ssh, docker-compose

Generally, my question is about being able to access ssh keys during docker-compose build.

I'm able to access my ssh keys when running docker-compose up using volume mapping in my docker-compose.yml file, looks like:

```
services:
    flask:
        volumes:
            - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
```

But I cannot access them during docker-compose build

**More Specifics**

I am running a python flask app. I want to install a private git repo as a pip package. So I added this line to requirements.txt

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/username/repo_name.git@branch_name
```

If I run bash in the service through `docker-compose run flask bash` then I can manually run `pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/username/repo_name.git@branch_name` and that works, because I have the volume mapping to the ssh keys.

But when I run docker-compose build, it cannot access the private git repo because it doesn't have access to the ssh keys.

Anyone know if there's a way to give docker-compose build access to ssh keys, or another way around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ssh is harder to setup than just using the username:password. Here is the line I added to requirements.txt that got it to work:

```
-e git+https://<username>:<password>@github.com/<path to git repo>.git#egg=<package_name>
```

If you want to get a specific tag, then you can do this:

```
-e git+https://<username>:<password>@github.com/<path to git repo>.git@<tag_name>#egg=<package_name>
```

You can use any username and password that has access to the git repo, but I recommend that you don't use your main git account for obvious security reasons. Create a new user specifically for this project, and grant them access rights.

Answer (score 4):

`volumes` are attached at *run time* of your container, NOT at *build time*.

Solution:

Copy your `.ssh` next to your `Dockerfile` and do the following in your `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY ./.ssh /root/.ssh
```

**Be careful:**

Like this, your .ssh directory will be available for everyone who has access to your Docker image. So either create a technical user and copy his .ssh into the image or (better) do something like this:

```
FROM baseimage AS builder
COPY ./.ssh /root/.ssh
RUN your commands

FROM baseimage
COPY --from=builder some-directory some-directory
```

**Edit:**
Another option is to use username:password instead of ssh key authentication. This way, you would use build args in your Dockerfile like:

```
FROM baseimage
ARG GIT_USER
ARG GIT_PASS
RUN git clone http://${GIT_USER}:${GIT_PASS}@your-git-url.git
```

and build it with args `docker build --build-args GIT_USER=<user> --build-args GIT_PASS=<pass> .`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It helped a little but it's still not working. It works with my own personal ssh keys. But I don't want to push them to github, so I created a new github user and granted them access rights to the repo.  But it won't work with this new user's keys. Everything else is exactly the same. My keys, it works, new user keys, it doesn't work. Any ideas? Where does docker-compose build look for ssh keys, is there an ssh-agent? (I can't see one)

Comment: I don't know your whole scenario: is it a private or public github repo? Who shall be able to build the image? But I recommend to add your .ssh to your .gitignore and add a hint to your README.md that whoever wants to build the image, has to put his ssh key into a specific folder. See also my edit on my answer.